# C# If Else Inside For Loop Didn't Work

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am creating a web application to import an excel file into MS Dynamics Crm. Here is the code snippet

```
for (i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (dt.Rows[i][3].ToString() != String.Empty)
    {
        try
        {
            Entity contractline = new Entity("new_contractline");
            contractline["new_lineitem"] = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
            contractline["new_sublineitem"] = dt.Rows[i][3].ToString();

            createChildData = service.Create(contractline);

            string guidString = createChildData.ToString();
            guidRecord[i] = guidString;

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    } 
    else if (dt.Rows[i][3].ToString() == string.Empty)  /**THIS BLOK BELOW WON'T FIRE **/
    {
        try
        {
            Entity contractline = new Entity("new_contractline");
              contractline["new_lineitem"] = dt.Rows[i][2].ToString();
              contractline["new_sublineitem"] = dt.Rows[i][3].ToString();
              contractline["new_quantity"] = "33";
             service.Create(contractline);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the **`else if`** block didn't fire when the `dt.Rows[i][3]` is empty. What could be the problem?

Comment: Add a Trace.Writeline in the exception handler to see if you are hitting an exception.

Comment: Is the value of `dt.Rows[i][3]` `NULL` or an empty string?

Comment: @Steve: Im not sure with that, on the excel field it was empty. So when i did this `dt.Rows[i][3].ToString()` i think i get an empty not null.

Comment: @FikriHailal well, it's pretty important to know. If it's `null` clearly it won't match `string.empty`. Besides, as you currently have your code you don't even need the `else if` just a simple `else` will suffice.

Comment: @Steve: When i change to `dt.Rows[i][3].ToString() == null` the program wont filter the records. All records will be imported into MS CRM. Also when i use `else` it don't make any different.

Comment: You say if you only use `else` it doesn't make any difference. For me this basically means the `else` part is never called or is always throwing an exception. Isn’t it possible for you to debug the code? You could also just write a message to the Output-Window in the `else` part with `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(“Else was called”);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just do `else`? If you don't have any other else-ifs.

```
if (dt.Rows[i][3].ToString() != String.Empty)
```

will fire if `.ToString()` is empty. However you will already get an exception here if `dt.Rows[i][3]` were null, because you can't `ToString()` on a null object. If you have a try catch outside of this code block, I suggest you check it out because `dt.Rows[i][3]` may be null and it is throwing the exception.

If you do have any other else-ifs, you should use

```
else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dt.Rows[i][3].ToString()))
```

and change your if block (actually I suggest you do this in any case)

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dt.Rows[i][3].ToString()))
```

Reason being is that not all spaces are actually the space bar character. You might be getting other [white space characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) which will not trigger your String.Empty block because it is not empty. This will match a number of spaces which your cell might have. This will also catch invisible non-spacebar spaces. An example is the equivalent of the HTML code `&nbsp;` (non-breaking space) which is not actually the spacebar space (and will not match " ") but will occupy space.

Comment: Thanks, i knew the problem is not coming from if else. It was my mistake because not place a right value wihtin this line `
              contractline["new_quantity"] = "33";`

Answer (score 0):

Just use If...Else with string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) like below....

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dt.Rows[i][3].ToString()) == true)
{
    // True.
    Console.WriteLine("Null or empty");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not null and not empty");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried below?
 else if (dt.Rows[i][3].ToString().Trim() == "")